# How can one be assured that generative models are not memorizing dataset, and that they will generate an unique image outside of dataset?

Tags: autoencoder, gan, generative-models, markov

If all GAN can do is capture the probability distribution of the dataset, then shouldn't they be similar to handing out images from the dataset?

How can we verify that the images that they generate are unique images outside of the dataset?